Why aren't my bookmarks being saved?
I've made a bunch of saves (questions and answers) over the past week or two on a particular topic. When I went to organize them in my Profile > Saves none of them are there. I've got some old ones organized into Lists. I saved a few today, tried questions and answers. One showed up, no others did. I checked that I hadn't saved a particular question before and sorted based on date.
Is this a technical problem, a policy issue? Is there a maximum? (Haven't seen anything about that) Any explanation for what's happening? Thanks!

update: requested logging*

click @ full.en.js?v=7bae6b63419b:1
(anonymous) @ stub.en.js?v=01af928a07d1:1
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/save/manage-save".
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
w @ full.en.js?v=7bae6b63419b:1
(anonymous) @ full.en.js?v=7bae6b63419b:1
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'speaker'.
Navigated to https://stackoverflow.com/users/saves/9915864/all
Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for <URL>.
Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for <URL>.


Cannot replicate.

Thanks for checking. So any ideas what's happening? I'm on a Windows machine, using Microsoft Edge. I've logged out and back in and flushed my cache over the last week, and didn't notice a difference.

Do you get a success response when saving? The "Question saved to [For later]    [Manage x]" Toast message that appears when saving posts.

I do get a 'Manage' flash response, which I followed. I'll try saving immediately from that for a while and see if the bookmarks stick around.

Can you keep the developer console open (hit F12) while you're clicking to add a post to your saves? Report any errors from the console that you encounter as an [edit]  in your question.

Added some logging above. It might take me a day to coordinate logging and a clean enough test run. Thanks for looking into this! Since I started saving the bookmark to a List right away, they seem to be saving. Some of my problem might be due to Cookie settings on the site. I don't see anything in Profile Preferences for setting anything though.

What extensions do you have installed?

I'm letting Microsoft Defender Smartscreen handle security instead of NoScript, which was having too many issues for a while.

OK, I THINK/HOPE it was user error. I said I sorted on date. I assumed Newest was the newest bookmark added to my list. Turns out Added is a date sort function, just no date associated with text. That's the one that sorts when bookmarks are added. Using Newest probably had my new bookmarks scattered in the list. Normally, a tiny little v/^ graphic is associated with date sorts.
